# What determines queue job status

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Didn't find an answer for this question, but I might have not worded it properly. In that case, sorry.

I'm getting into Laravel's queued jobs to dispatch item deliveries in a game (basically boils down to sending a HTTP request and receiving a response). I ran into a wall though. How does Laravel determine whether a job has failed or succeeded? What exactly classifies it as failed?

Comment: Basically, from my knowledge, if any php errors are encountered or if any uncaught exception occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A job is considered failed if it throws an unhandled exception for every attempt to run the job. This is done in [Worker::process](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/242d438700597aa6bdcbc8a21a14fe3a241c91a3/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php#L317-L320) which forwards exceptions to [handleJobException](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/242d438700597aa6bdcbc8a21a14fe3a241c91a3/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php#L332-L368) which in turn calls [markJobAsFailedIfWillExceedMaxAttempts](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/242d438700597aa6bdcbc8a21a14fe3a241c91a3/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php#L401-L421).
2. A job can use the [InteractsWithQueue trait](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/242d438700597aa6bdcbc8a21a14fe3a241c91a3/src/Illuminate/Queue/InteractsWithQueue.php) and call [fail($exception = null)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/242d438700597aa6bdcbc8a21a14fe3a241c91a3/src/Illuminate/Queue/InteractsWithQueue.php#L38-L49) to signal that it has failed.